# Where to find a website created using WordPress locally

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

My question is: Does WordPress store websites locally in organised hierarchical folders, and is it possible to copy this folder and paste it somewhere else, so I can open the website locally by clicking an index.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not store static HTML-files on the server. It uses PHP template files which get the page contents from the wordpress database dynamically.

If you would just like to have an offline version of your site for development or presentation you can install a local WordPress using a tool like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html).